# How to split values of a Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, key-value

I have a dictionary like this:

```
data = {
key1: [ <A><B> ]
key2: [ <C><D> ]
key3: [ <A><F> ]
...
}
```

## **Goal to achieve:**

I want to have instead something like this:

```
new_dict = {
key1: [ <A>, <B> ]
key2: [ <C>, <D> ]
key3: [ <A>, <F> ]
...
}
```

And then extract only the keys with "< A>" as first value and save them in a list. Something like this:

```
A_as_first_value = [key1, key3]
```

After having a list with all these keys, I also want a list with all the second values. Something like this:

```
second_values_ = [<B>, <F>]
```

Comment: Can you add some python valid object as your input data?

Comment: Could you provide some code samples with **valid** python syntax?

Comment: You can use a regular expression with `re.findall()` to split the strings.

Comment: Please, can you provide a valid Python syntax?

Comment: Thanks all, I've edited my question with a (hoping) more valid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User regular expression to findall the substrings matching the pattern `<\w>` where `\w` basically means a word character, then filter out the keys for the resulting list of values.

```py
import re
pattern=re.compile('<\w>')
out={k:pattern.findall(v[0]) for k,v in data.items()} # data is your dict
# out
# {'key1': ['<A>', '<B>'], 'key2': ['<C>', '<D>'], 'key3': ['<A>', '<F>']}
A_as_first_value = [k for k in out if out[k][0]=='<A>']
# A_as_first_value
# ['key1', 'key3']
```

Then from the resulting list of keys above, get the values at second index for values in the given keys in the resulting dictionary:

```py
second_values=[out[k][1] for k in A_as_first_value]
# second_values
# ['<B>', '<F>']
```